# How to install BR30 lights instead of LED

Tags: lighting, ceiling

I  have LED downlights installed, and I want to use BR30 bulbs. I want to convert this setup to enable BR30.

I have no clue about electricity but I'm willing to learn. Just need a push in the right direction.

I have attached the setup.

The light:

[image: The light]

LED Driver:

[image: LED driver]

Connection:

[image: The connection]

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Simply unplug LED driver from the connector, buy a socket, wire the wires that were going from the ceiling-> connector, to ceiling-> new socket.

Answer (score 0):

### Don't use incandescents in LED housings!

You need to look closely at the downlight assembly. But if it was sold as an LED downlight, most likely **it is not designed to handle** the additional heat which is generated by the inefficient incandescent bulbs. You're violating the electrical code and fire code, and if you have a house fire, your insurance will not want to pay.

I know there are many incandescent luddites, and many more who tried LEDs before they were really market ready and were put off by the blueness, bad color rendering, bad dimming, early failure of cheap units, etc.  If you want to use incandescent downlights, fine, buy downlight enclosures *made for incandescents.*

Honestly I would go back to LED of the latest types.  The problems with blueness, glare, unnatural appearance and dimmable have been solved. If you want the best appearance, go for an LED with an 80+ color rendering index (CRI).  Separately you can select color temperature: 6500K is daylight (which is very blue). Common fluorescent lights are 4100K.  Halogen is 3000K. Traditional incandescent is 2700K.  They are more dimmable than incandescents, they don't shift yellow-orange at low light levels.   You have many options.  Also, cheap units are still cheap, and tend to have all of the above problems.

I changed many of the bulbs in my house to LED screw-in.  My girlfriend does not like nasty blue glary LEDs, but I asked her to tell me which was which.  She couldn't.